# Flutter FutureBuilder Not Updating

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a Flutter FutureBuilder that needs to be updated with new data given by the user. However, the UI elements in the FutureBuilder do not update and still contain the old values. I have checked through print statements that the new data is correctly loaded. The issue seems to be with FutureBuilder rebuilding the widget when the new data is loaded. Any help is appreciated.

```
Future<List<PollItem>> fetchPost(String loc) async {
  return new Future(() async {

    final response = await http
        .post(restip + '/getPosts',
        body: {"data": loc});

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print(response.body);

      // If the call to the server was successful, parse the JSON
      // This function adds json to list
      PollItem.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));

      // list is a list of posts gathered based on the string criteria
      return list;
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load polls');
    }
  });
}

class PollState extends State<Poll> {
  TextEditingController textc = new TextEditingController();

  static String dropDowntext = "City";
  String _name = "Search";
  final _names = [''];


  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    print("dropdown"+dropDowntext);
    textc.text = _name;
    print(dropDowntext);
    return FutureBuilder<List<PollItem>>(
      future: fetchPost(dropDowntext),
      initialData: [PollItem()],
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          print(snapshot.data[0].question);
          });
}
```

Here is my global file:

```
 List<PollItem> list = new List();
      factory PollItem.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        int len = json['length'];
        if(listNum!=len) {
          listNum = len;
          list.clear();
          for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            list.add(PollItem(
              answer1: json[i.toString()]['answer1'],
              location: json[i.toString()]['location']

            )
            );
          }
        }
        }
```

Comment: Are you calling `setState` somewhere in `PollState`?

Comment: what is your 'list' variable?

Comment: Yes, I am calling setState when I get the updated value for dropDowntext. My list variable is a List of objects that is stored in another class. I have added the code in the question to reflect that.

Comment: could you print list.length before return list; ? what is the result ?

Comment: Yes, I printed it and it is 1. There is one data element being returned.

Comment: You aren't returning anything in your futurebuilder ?

Comment: @Ian Sorry for the confusion. I removed the return statement for the sake of simplifying the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to create a `Future` object :

```
   Future<List<PollItem>> fetchPost(String loc) async {
    final response = await http.post(restip + '/getPosts',body: {"data": loc});

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        print(response.body);
        final data = json.decode(response.body);
        int len = data['length'];
        final List<PollItem> newList = List();
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
          newList.add(PollItem(
          answer1: data[i.toString()]['answer1'],
          location: data[i.toString()]['location']
            )
          );
        }

        print("new list size: ${newList.length}");

        return newList;
      } else {
        throw Exception('Failed to load polls');
      }
      return null;
  }
```

Comment: I made this change and it still seems to display the old data.

Comment: I updated the code, could you try again? whats the value of 'new list size: ... ' ?

Comment: also try to add the code of the PollState , it looks like is incomplete

Comment: Thank you for your help. I made the changes, but I am getting some compilation errors. Do I need to wrap it in a Future? If not, I probably need to change the return type right?

Comment: sorry I think I forgot the type :  final List<PollItem> newList = List();

Comment: This solution works and I am able to print the right value. However, none of the UI elements are showing up even though the list length is 1. Any idea why that might be?

Comment: @diegoveloper Could you please help me out to find out the problem on my this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64540805/why-futurebuilder-callback-is-not-calling-after-facebook-logged-in-data-in-flutt